# Virtualbox port forwarding with docker

Tags: docker, virtualbox, portforwarding, dinghy

I'm running `virtualbox` locally and I've used port forwarding like this

```
0.0.0.0:7000 -> 0.0.0.0:7000
```

so that I can do

```
curl http://localhost:7000
```

from host to vm and be able to communicate with the application running in the vm and listening to port `7000`.

Is it possible to make the reverse? I want to set a port forward to be able to

```
curl http://localhost:6000
```

from my vm and be able to communicate with the app that runs on host and listens on port `6000`.

I'm using `NAT`.

I already know about bridged network and about using the network IP of my host. I can't use those. All I'm interested in is the above.

Exclaimer:

The reason of the limitations above is because I'm using `dinghy` with `docker` and `docker-machine`. If I change the network to something else than `NAT` the setup will break. Moreover I can't use something else than `localhost` since these are the defaults that the apps have and I need them to communicate as if they were running both on host.

Comment: So docker runs inside vm? What's the host OS?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add that, Mac OSX El Capitan

Comment: I think there are three possible options: 1. Setup an SSH tunnel with `ssh -R`, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work. 2. Setup Nginx or Apache reverse proxy on the vm to forward traffic to host. 3. Force the VM to think `localhost` is your host ip by adding it to the `/etc/hosts` file (this has the potential risk of breaking other services that may depend on localhost being 127.0.0.1)

Comment: @warmoverflow can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @alkis can you recommend some source how to do port forwarding for docker to run localhost on browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options:

1. Setup an SSH tunnel with ssh -R, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work
2. Setup Nginx or Apache reverse proxy on the vm to forward traffic to host.
3. Force the VM to think localhost is your host ip by adding it to the /etc/hosts file (this has the potential risk of breaking other services that may depend on localhost being 127.0.0.1)